# GET и POST запрос

Tags: jquery, post, php, get

здравствуйте знатоки!Подскажите пожалуйста!Умееться скрипт отправки Аяксом сообщнеий на сервер.

```
            $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "insert.php",
            data: "message_wall=" + wall_post,
            success: function () {
                $('ul#posts').prepend(wall_post);

            }
        });
```

Он показан выше.А теперь суть вопроса ... Как этот запрос можно получить обработчиком ?!И можно ли его переделать в POST как это будет правильно выглядеть!Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
$message_wall = $_GET['message_wall']; /* если был метод GET */
/* Здесь буде сам обработчик */
echo "ID статьи $message_wall";
```

И т.д. Аналогично `$_POST`;

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> data: "message_wall=" + wall_post,
> ```

Меняешь на

```
data: { message_wall: wall_post },
```

а дальше обычным способом, как если бы в форме был input с таким именем.

PS: Впрочем, неизменённый вариант тоже работает. Но там экранирования нет.